# Tax not being applied to Simple Products

Tags: configurable-product, tax, simple-product

I have a strange problem where I have applied identical tax settings to a configurable product and a simple product - the configurable product is calculating the tax okay but the simple product is not.

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution - the attribute setting for tax_class_id was only set to one product type - I changed it to All Product Types and solved my problem!